# Mysterious Disappearances

Tags: riddle

> Two twins swam out to lake,
>   Only one came home.
>   Four twins swam out to sea
>   Only two came home.
>   Why did the other three twins,
>   Never come home?
>   The three who disappeared
>   Never existed,
>   Unless they were spotted.
>   Twins were never murdered
>   They were never killed
>   They just disappeared
>   When you couldn't see them.

Comment: This has potential to be too broad.

Comment: Okay revised it

Comment: Its supposed ti be three twins not six twins, my "mathing" is bad

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is best explained if:

> Half of the "twins" were the reflections on the water. Swimmers began during the day, when there was a reflection, but returned at night, when there wasn't enough ambient light to reflect.

Maybe that's not well said, but it ties in with

> Half the twins in each case not returning

And

> They aren't the real people, so they never existed.

Comment: No, you're actually right! Great job!

Comment: Well, the fourth explanation is incorrect. You're first three is incorrect. Just revise it (make it sound more confident now that you know its the answer) and I'll accept it! +1

Comment: Well done! Accepted

Answer (score 0):

> They never came home because they couldn't swim at all?

Comment: Sorry, incorrect!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be

> They were already home?

Comment: Sorry, incorrect!